# Keep Elastic Beanstalk in Updating Grey State

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application with several custom `container_commands` that run on deployment. Everything works fine, but when creating a new environment or rebuilding an environment, the health status goes from grey to red, then finally to green after all the `container_commands` have executed successfully (because the health check fails until the `container_commands` are complete). Is there any way i can keep the environment health status as grey until the container_commands have completed? I have tried setting the `HealthCheckGracePeriod` and `UnhealthyThreshold` to a high enough value but these don't seem to have any impact at all on the time before the environment goes from grey to red. I'd like to do this so that our environment doesn't unnecessarily/incorrectly generate alerts/emails about being unhealthy.

The documentation indicates that `HealthCheckGracePeriod` should do the trick:

```
HealthCheckGracePeriod
The length of time in seconds after a new EC2 instance comes into service that Auto Scaling starts checking its health.
```

but I see no difference when specifying this value.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's a mechanism for this. You could, in theory, inject a container command to fire up a server on port 80 to receive health checks, and then tear it down before the application launches, but that's a pretty elaborate workaround.

Comment: That would also erroneously indicate that an instance is online and cause load balancer traffic to be directed to that instance

Comment: I added a custom WaitCondition + Handle + call to cfn-signal.exe and that worked.